# How to keep track of and sort pointers without using malloc in C?

Tags: c, pointers

I would like to know if anyone has a suggestion for keeping track of and sorting some pointers. Each pointer points to a struct (struct1_t) which contains some elements.

I also need to be able to (very quickly) find the struct1_t with the most amount of elements to add new ones to (full ones are removed from the list), but struct1_t s may change the number of elements they have (increment fullest or decrement random only), so I need to be able to update this within this storage quickly. All new struct1_t have 0 elements when added, or (MAX - 1) elements.

However, the challenge here is that I don't know a way to use a linked list, because unfortunately, I'm not able to use malloc. I can only allocate and free entire pages (or multiples) at once.

Comment: You can still use linked lists, even if you can't use malloc.  The pointers don't have to be dynamically allocated, and point to structure members.

Comment: @Max, seems like the best idea so far. I might try this, I suppose having an array of { void* data; void* next; void* prev } could work? Although I'm still unsure of how to implement something such as that, the fine details elude me, although I will try my best.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do like this, define a struct

```
struct node{
     int data;
     struct node *prev;
     struct node *next;
};
```

If you can't use malloc, you can declare a global array

```
struct node elements[ENOUGH_SPACE];
```

then use each element of this array like the malloc's result, like

```
struct node *p = &elements[i];
p->next = ...
p->prev = ...
```

Comment: I don't really see a way to utilize this, sorry. But for my purpose ENOUGH_SPACE doesn't exist. I need a dynamically expanding solution because I may have many "elements". For example, 3276800 elements is reasonable that I might encounter.

Comment: TL;DR: I need it to expand dynamically with page based allocations.

Comment: @NotaName How will you have a dynamically growing "list"/"set" without using some sort of allocations, which in the end will mean that somewhere `malloc` has to be called, even if it's not in your code?

Comment: I can use mmap (or, my wrapper around it, palloc). That doesn't need malloc. Where does malloc get IT'S memory from? Either mmap or brk or sbrk. s/brk is unusable for me, and mmap does page size multiples only, hence why I said I can only allocate pages.